# Qt + VS2010: moc: Too many input files specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt-vs-addin

Trying to compile my simple Qt app in visual studio with the VS-addin for Qt, I receive the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: XXXXXXXXXXXXX, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/05/2012 6:57:33 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "release\XXXXXXXXXXXXX.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "release\XXXXXXXXXXXXX.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>CustomBuild:
1>  MOC XXXXXXXXXXXXXMainWidget.h
1>  moc: Too many input files specified
1>  Usage: moc [options] <header-file>
1>    -o<file>           write output to file rather than stdout
1>    -I<dir>            add dir to the include path for header files
1>    -E                 preprocess only; do not generate meta object code
1>    -D<macro>[=<def>]  define macro, with optional definition
1>    -U<macro>          undefine macro
1>    -i                 do not generate an #include statement
1>    -p<path>           path prefix for included file
1>    -f[<file>]         force #include, optional file name
1>    -nn                do not display notes
1>    -nw                do not display warnings
1>    @<file>            read additional options from file
1>    -v                 display version of moc
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5):                       error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
 1>
 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05
 ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What's the deal? I googled it, and the issue appeared to be a bug in 1.1.7. The solution was to rejigger the includes in the VS project. That said, I would prefer to stay with 1.1.10 - it is only a month old and I am sure that the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: It appears so, even after qmake remade with no spaces in the path - it appears to have stayed. I will delete some things and try again.

Comment: Yep. This was picking up an old environmental variable which had spaces in the paths. If you submit this as a reply I will mark it as an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen if you have spaces in your filenames or paths.

There might be workarounds with some form of quoting, but the most sane (IMO) way of dealing with this is to simply avoid using spaces in your project path and filenames.

Comment: And when you don't get to name the project; what then?